# Decrypting a Caesar Cipher with ord() and chr()?

Tags: python, decoding, caesar-cipher

I have an assignment for a lab that asks me to decrypt an input file that has been encrypted with a ceasar cipher. As background, my instructor has already let everyone know that the cipher has a shift distance of three.

I was able to get my to write to an output file, but my output.txt is completely unreadable, and not close at all to what the expected output should be. I remember my instructor mentioning that we could use ord() and chr() combined with arithmetic to transform the encoded characters to plaintext.

```
decode = inpf.readlines()
for line in decode:
    output = ""
    c = str()
    for c in line:
        if c >= "a" and c <= "z":
            x = ord(c)
            x += 23
            x %= 26
            y = chr(x)
            output = output + y
        if c >= "A" and c <= "Z": 
            x = ord(c)
            x += 23
            x %= 26
            y = chr(x)
            output = output + y
        else:
            output = output + c

    outf.write(output + "\n")
```

I appreciate any help or advice you can offer! Thanks!!

EDIT:
Sample Input: "Wkh Orug Ri Wkh Ulqjv:"
Output: "    :"
Expected Output: "The Lord Of The Rings:"

Comment: Could you include the sample input, output and expected output?

Comment: If you `x %= 26` you are setting the value of `x` to something outside its ascii character range. At a minimum, you should be offsetting this result so it is placed back within the ascii range.

Comment: Can you use the `string` module? Doing so would give access to `string.ascii_letters` which would give you zero-indexed access to the ascii alphabet.

Comment: `c = str(); for c in line:` -  This is very bad. You are creating an inner alias for `c` within the `for` loop, causing the outer `c` string to be ignored.

Comment: I don't believe that my instructor wants us to use any modules to decode the cipher.

Comment: https://medium.com/@lazyendian_bit/caesar-cipher-python-implementation-982593f1ab45 ... My code u can take reference from there . python based code with encryption and decryption both functionality

Comment: As @h0r53 mentioned you don't need to initialize c= str()... Your logic is wrong brother also ASCII don't work like this .. (65+23)%26 or (97+23)%26 which is wrong even your code will never work on edge cases like 68+23 . it will not be a alphanumeric char. And on decryption you will subtract I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ord() method in Python converts a character into its Unicode code value. Capital 'A' starts from unicode 65 and small 'a' from 97. Also you should use 'elif' instead of second 'if' statement. Otherwise, in case of a small letter, the letter will repeat. You need to get the letters position in alphabet, apply the shift and convert it back to unicode. A working example of your code is given below:

```
inpf = open("input.txt",'r')
outf = open("output.txt",'w')

decode = inpf.readlines()
for line in decode:
    output = ""
    c = str()
    for c in line:
        if c >= "a" and c <= "z":
            x = ord(c) - 97 #small a
            x -= 3
            x = (x+26)%26 #For handling negative numbers
            y = chr(x + 97)
            output = output + y
        elif c >= "A" and c <= "Z": 
            x = ord(c) - 65 #Capital A
            x -= 3
            x = (x+26)%26 #For handling negative numbers
            y = chr(x + 65)
            output = output + y
        else:
            output = output + c

    outf.write(output + "\n")
```